# Why is Configuration Manager 2012 creating a SMSPKG folder on my C: drive?

Tags: sccm, system-center, sccm-2012, configuration-management

I'm testing System Center Configuration Manager 2012, and I installed it on a server with two disks (using a SQL Server instance on a second server). Before installing, I created a file called `no_sms_on_drive.sms` on my system drive (C:). As expected, most SCCM folders got created on the second drive (whych, BTW, has a lot more free space). Most, but not one.

I have a folder called `SMSPKG` on my C: drive, shared as `SMS_CPSC$`, with the description "SMS Compressed Package Storage". I don't even know what is it for, but I know I don't want it on my system drive.

Also, I know I can specify the drives to use when creating a distribution point; but I haven't done this yet, just the basic SCCM setup, I didn't enable neither a management point nor a distribution point yet.

How did that folder get there?

And how can I move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for the distribution point, I believe by default your site management server has to be a DP as well, even if you don't store any packages on it. There are articles out there for how to move it, but this is why it ended up there in the first place. Also, once it moves the name will change as well, moving to the f drive for example it will become `SMS_CPSF$`, in case you're looking for it in the future and can't find it. If you don't plan on using that server for a DP then it will stay empty.